# How to give name to type of custom data structure class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change the name of type of object i.e., Data Structure that i have built.

**Code:**

```
class LinkedStack:
   pass

>>> s = LinkedStack()
```

**Actual Ouput:**

```
>>> type(s)
<class '__main__.LinkedStack'>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
>>> type(s)
<class 'LinkedStack'>
```

Is it possible to change the type of class? If yes, please tell me the process.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Is it not possible with `type(s)`?

Comment: If you want your class to be named `linked_stack`, it seems like step one should be *naming it* `linked_stack`: `class linked_stack: ...`. That said, naming your classes like that is a bad idea, like trying to make your kid's legal name `bob_johnson` instead of `Bob Johnson`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the response. When we check `type([1])`, it gives `<class 'list'>`. I'm expecting similar to that. Type of that Data Structure should be `<class 'LinkedStack'>`. Is it possible? Edited question accordingly.

Comment: Worrying about this is a waste of your time and of the time of the programmer who will have to maintain it. The `type` object is mostly the purview of the standard library; leave it alone unless you have a functional reason to do something with it. (And you pretty much never have a good functional reason to do anything with it. This certainly isn't one.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, I don't have any functional reason for now. I was interested to know, is it possible to do that or not, because I haven't seen something like this before.